# If a dropdown value is selected, how do I add it to another column and then gather the sums?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

So I have a dropdown in Col K with "Apple, Oranges, Grapes, Cherries".

If a kid wants to order a specific fruit, I want it to auto-populate the section of Col N in green and then sum the total quantity needed to order into Col O.

My expected values are on the bottom right... How do I accomplish this black magic?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- paste in first green cell:

  ```
  =QUERY(K:L; "select K,sum(L) 
               where K is not null 
               group by K 
               label sum(L)''"; 0)
  ```

  [image: 0]